# Using paste0 to fill in an argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let me start by saying I'm sure this has been answered before but I am unsure of what terms to search.

I have a few data frames that are named like `df_A ,  df_B , and df_C` and wish to send them all to `ggplot`. I tried to loop through them all but have been unsuccessful. Here is what I have now:

```
for (Param in c("A","B","C"){
  chosen_df <- paste0("df_",Param)
  ggplot(data=chosen_df...)
}
```

I receive back an error saying "data must be a data frame". This error makes sense to me since `chosen_df` is character vector rather than the actual data frame.

I have tried using `noquote` but to no avail.

My questions are:
  1) What kind of search terms can I look up to solve this problem
  2) How close am I to solving this problem?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `get` to return the value of the object names as a string

```
for (Param in c("A","B","C"){
   chosen_df <- get(paste0("df_",Param))
    ggplot(data=chosen_df, ...)
  }
```

---

Or with `mget`, return the values in a `list`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^df_[A-Z]$'))
```